# SQL LIMIT returns no results where no LIMIT returns results

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM mm_tfs 
WHERE product_slug LIKE '%football%' 
    AND schoolid = '8' AND category_id ='21'
LIMIT 4
```

Returns 4 values like I'm asking, but the following statement returns 0 - is there a rule about using the OR statement that I'm not familiar with?  My assumption is that it should return all of the values in 1 (or more if it weren't for the limit).

```
SELECT * FROM mm_tfs 
WHERE (product_slug LIKE '%football%' 
   AND schoolid = '8' AND category_id ='21') 
OR (product_description LIKE '%football%' 
   AND schoolid = '8' AND category_id ='21') 
LIMIT 4
```

<sub>**NOTE by cyberkiwi** The first OR portion of Q2 is exactly the same as the WHERE clause on Q1</sub>

```
product_description LIKE '%football%' AND schoolid = '8' AND category_id ='21
```

Without the OR Statement by itself does produce the desired result as long as it does not have the limit.  When the OR statement is used with the LIMIT as well, there are 0 values returned.

```
SELECT * FROM mm_tfs 
WHERE product_description LIKE '%football%' 
    AND schoolid = '8' AND category_id ='21'
LIMIT 4
```

^-- That produces 0 results

```
SELECT * FROM mm_tfs 
WHERE product_description LIKE '%football%' 
    AND schoolid = '8' AND category_id ='21'
```

^-- That produces results

**The strangest part of this is that all of these queries product the right effect in my PHPMYADMIN SQL query window, but not in the application itself.**

Comment: Looks to be a boolean logic error rather then specific to OR.  Wrap the entire thing around braces, that is your entire condition around ( and ).

Comment: This is very interesting. Can someone explain why it's wrong instead of giving alternate approach? +1

Comment: I edited the question but can you confirm again that the queries are as shown? Are the queries formatted by PHP or are you running from console directly?

Comment: @Nishant - I dont have mySQL, but to me it is probably some boolean logic error.  That is why I suggested to strip down the query by removing some conditions, testing, and only then readding the stripped parts given the issue goes away.

Comment: @JonH I donot think so. I visualize this way, MySQL engine goes to a row and the compare against first of OR block. It maches and result returned. Since both OR condition are same this _should_ work, unless OP did some mistake in copying the exact query from his console to SO.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. Try posting your table definition.

Comment: I would post that bug on MySQL. Attach your Db if possible, and include the exact MySQL version

Comment: Is LIKE '%variable%' case sensitive?

Comment: @cyberkiwi I cant reproduce this.

Comment: Another reason not to use mySQL.  Sorry just had to...

Comment: @Bob Caveza: We'd need your MySQL version, table definition and if possible some data from that table to see if it can be reproduced.

Comment: @JonH: Yeah... another example of assumptions based on incomplete data. Sorry, just had to.

Comment: Can you do an EXPLAIN for `all queries`? I suspect MySQL is doing something funny.  You're not using this a s subquery somewhere else are you?

Comment: @Mchl - I don't know I remember mySQL having a bug in the number of days in a month....

Comment: @JonH: Congratulations on sweet memories (I'd be grateful if you provided a bug #). Notice however, that in the case on hand nobody was able to reproduce the behaviour so far.

Comment: MySQL - 5.0.77-log if that helps

Comment: @Mchl - Thanks for the congrats it made me smile :)

Comment: @Bob Cavezza: I reviewed changelogs for a few versions following 5.0.77 and didn't see anything indicating there was a bug like this. Please add the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE mm_tfs` to your question (you should be able to edit it)

Comment: Are school_id and category_id really text, not integers?

Comment: Wow! This question has gotten way longer since I favorited it. (however, all my favorites are temporary. I did up vote the question though)

Comment: No, I was wrong about school_id (it is integer), but categoryid is varchar - Comes from affiliate program api using letters as well as numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are repeating some of the conditions which is not necessary. Try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM mm_tfs 
WHERE 
   (product_slug LIKE '%football%' 
 OR product_description LIKE '%football%')
   AND schoolid = '8' 
   AND category_id ='21'
LIMIT 4
```

**UPDATE:**

I have created the following table:

```
create table mm_tfs2 (schoolid varchar(2), categoryid varchar(2), 
                      description varchar(20), slug varchar(20));
```

And 5 times:

```
insert into mm_tfs2 values (8, 21, '', 'football');
```

And finally the query:

```
select * from mm_tfs2 where 
(slug like '%football%' and schoolid = 8 and categoryid = 21) 
or (description like '%football%' and schoolid = 8 and categoryid = 21) 
limit 4;
+----------+------------+-------------+----------+
| schoolid | categoryid | description | slug     |
+----------+------------+-------------+----------+
| 8        | 21         |             | football |
| 8        | 21         |             | football |
| 8        | 21         |             | football |
| 8        | 21         |             | football |
+----------+------------+-------------+----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I'm sorry to say that I'm not able to recreate the problem.

Comment: While that is true, does it explain why the query doesn't work?

Comment: @cyberwiki: lets see your answer, smarty pants :p

Comment: @VoodooChild - we're trying to figure out why OR doesn't work. This answer doesn't solve that

Comment: @cyberkiwi: Yes, I am interested to know why it doesn't work as well.

Comment: Yeah, you're right... it doesn't explain why the OP's query doesn't work. Hmmmm...

Comment: @cyberkiwi, I'm not able to reproduce the problem on my own mysql server.

Comment: @Bob Cavezza, it works fine on my server with and without the `LIMIT`. I wonder what your table definition looks like.

Comment: @Klaus everything is setup as varchar utf8_general_ci - is this what you're referring to?

Comment: @Bob, having changed the ids from ints to varchar I'm still not able to reproduce the problem :-(

Comment: Wow, definitely going above and beyond, but I'm afraid it may be a lost cause.  I really appreciate the help.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put ( ) arround the entire condition

```
( (...AND...) OR (...AND...) )
```

Like so:

```
  SELECT * FROM mm_tfs WHERE 
  (  (product_slug LIKE '%football%' AND schoolid = '8' AND category_id ='21') 
   OR (product_description LIKE '%football%' AND schoolid = '8' AND category_id   
   ='21')
  ) LIMIT 4
```

Comment: Nope, doesn't change result set from 0

Comment: Would he need these brackets if he didn't have `LIMIT 4` statement?

Comment: @Bob Cavezza - Eliminate small pieces to see the issue.  For example, get rid of the 2 ANDs from the OR portion and have it just or product_description LIKE '%football%'...Then see if any rows come back.  I would make use of  ( and ) some more.  These AND's and ORs could screw this up for ya...

Comment: I did - that second statement returns expected values just as the first statement did - which makes this even more perplexing

Answer (score 1):

I *think* you could clean it up a little bit, you're getting only rows for one school, and one category ID, so there's no reason that you should have to check for those both times:

```
SELECT *
FROM mm_tfs
WHERE schoolid = '8'
    AND category_id ='21'
    AND (product_slug LIKE '%football%'
         OR product_description LIKE '%football%')
LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Hmm, beaten by Klaus.  Need to be quicker next time.  :P

Comment: LOL @galador, you have all the time in the world to explain WTH going on here (see the comments in OP). I'll upvote for nailing it.